# Angularjs - Component in head tag

Tags: angularjs

Is it posible enter a component inside the head tag html to my index.html? would be like this,

This the index.html code:

```
<head>
<testing-path></testing-path>
</head
<body>
</body>
```

I think you can not because the general module is on the body tag

```
<body ng-app="app">
```

This is the html code to component (testingPath.component.html):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{vm.valueURL}}"></script>
```

This is the component code to controller (testingPath.component.js):

```
    function testingPathController($rootScope) {
      var vm = this;
      vm.valueURL = "url";
   }
```

Thank you for the help,

Comment: What do you want to achieve ?

Comment: I want to load a js file, for to use throughout the APP, but it has to be parameterized the src script property and get it from a json file

Comment: If you want to load the js file to use throughout the APP, you can directly place it inside body or head depending on your requirement. Why do you need component for that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add ng-app on the html tag rather than the body tag.

```
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <testing-path></testing-path>
  </head
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

But ... I think that this isn't a good idea, you can load the script in the body tag.

This way :

```
<head>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
  [...]
  <testing-path></testing-path>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place the ng-app directive in the html tag for a global scope of the module in your html, but if you put it in the body you can only use it into body